# eclipse "unsurround" selection (remove try/catch, if etc block)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> having selected some text in the JDT editor one is presented with the "surround with" menu. I sometimes feel the need to do the opposite - easily remove a try catch or if block etc. So is there any way to do this (there are ways to select everything in a block so it would be easy programmatically - so maybe there is a plugin offering it ?) ?
If no way exists a bug report in eclipse jdt would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think it's a trivial enhancement, I'd suggest [raising a JDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT) whose severity is "enhancement" as explained in the [Eclipse wiki](http://goo.gl/804yDy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse you can click within the `catch` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and select "Remove catch clause."

Comment: Omg - actually your best bet is to click just after the `{` but it works and moreover works for most "surround - with" blocks ! Moreover CTRL+1 gives more options on some blocks (like on a switch --> _Convert switch to if-else_). So I guess I got my answer - please add a link to the docs so I can accept this

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there are any plug-ins or shortcuts to remove try/catch blocks

p.s I'm not sure what a bug report is or how to make one

I hope this is enough to answer your question fully